# Can we integrate Jmeter and New Relic Reporting?

Tags: jmeter, newrelic

Can anyone let me know if there is a an integration of jmeter with new relic? 
I am looking for single platform to view the reports from both of them ?

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [Plugin for JMeter](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/plugin-for-jmeter/36643) discussion at the NewRelic forum the [NR Support guy mentions](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/plugin-for-jmeter/36643/2) there is a [BlazeMeter Integration with NewRelic](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732629-BlazeMeter-s-Integration-With-New-Relic) which you can consider given BlazeMeter is 100% JMeter-compatible hence you should be able to run your tests via their cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Loadium](https://loadium.com) a freemium testing tool which integrate JMeter with NewRelic

> Discover bottlenecks during test execution with New Relic and App Dynamics integration.